# The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to access data from Firestore real-time database, but I get this message all the time and other couple messages. how can I access the data in this situation? Thank you in advance

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      FirestoreCrud firestoreCrudRef = new FirestoreCrud();
      Stream<QuerysnapShop> blogsSnapShot;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        firestoreCrudRef.readData().then((result) {
          blogsSnapShot = result;
        });
        super.initState();
      }
    
      Widget blogList() {
        return Container(
          child: StreamBuilder<QuerysnapShop>(
              stream: blogsSnapShot,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return BlogTile(
                      author: snapshot.data.documents[index].data()['author'],
                      title: snapshot.data.documents[index].data()['tile'],
                      body: snapshot.data.documents[index].data()['body'],
                      imageUrl: snapshot.data.documents[index].data()['imageUrl'],
                    );
                  },
                );
              }),
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was that I was using

```
StreamBuilder()
```

and had to change to

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>()
```

and then use

```
.docs
```

instead of

```
.documents
```

Answer (score 5):

The `QuerySnapshot` class has a `docs` property, which then return a `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>`. You can then access an index from this List which gives you a `QueryDocumentSnapshot` that you can then acess its `.data()` method to have a `Map<String, dynamic>`. Finally you can access any field from that.

Try:

```
snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['imageUrl'],
```

Comment: Thank you Perdro. That was a great explanation. I checked Firestore https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage . But the realtime db didnt  talk about Docs part .    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
          return Text("Full Name: ${data['full_name']} ${data['last_name']}");
        }

Answer (score 3):

The below code should help you achieve the desired result.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    var temp = snapshot.data.docs[index].data();
    return BlogTile(
      author: temp['author'],
      title: temp['tile'],
      body: temp['body'],
      imageUrl: temp['imageUrl'],
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Thank you Preet , That was very helpful. Appreciate it

Comment: Happy to help .

Answer (score 1):

The solution by preet shah wont work anymore. The below worked for me:

```dart
 return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var temp = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                return Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Card(
                    child: Text(temp['full_name']),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
```