# The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot' Cloud Firestore Update

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I upgraded Flutter to this version

```
cloud_firestore: `^0.16.0`
```

I read about the change Firestore to FirebaseStore but I can't resolve this:

```
data = snapshot.documents[0].data;
```

I tried:

```
data = snapshot.docs[0].data;
```

But throw an error.

```
CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(''); 
collectionReference.snapshots().listen((snapshot) { data = snapshot.documents[0].data;
```

> The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot' Cloud Firestore Update

Comment: The error message shows that you're still calling `documents` somewhere, while the property is now called `docs`: https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docs.html. There's not much more we can do here based on what you're showing. You'll have to find the line that causes that error, and update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cloud_firestore package you have to use,

```
data = snapshot.docs[0].data();
```

use () at the end of the data.

Answer (score 0):

As Puf mentioned, if your app is following the latest version, the property is now called as `docs` however, somewhere on your app is still calling `documents` property of QuerySnapshot which doesn't exist.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66261228/7031308) further explains it as well.

Doc Image:

[image]