# Flutter The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot<Object>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error in my flutter app:

**The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'.
Try importing the library that defines 'documents', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'documents'.**

Here is my code:

```
  getExpenseItems(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    List<ElementTask> listElement = new List(), listElement2;
    Map<String, List<ElementTask>> userMap = new Map();

    List<String> cardColor = new List();
    if (widget.user.uid.isNotEmpty) {
      cardColor.clear();

      snapshot.data.documents.map<List>((f) {
        f.data.forEach((a, b) {
          if (b.runtimeType == bool) {
            listElement.add(new ElementTask(a, b));
          }
          if (b.runtimeType == String && a == "color") {
            cardColor.add(b);
          }
        });
        listElement2 = new List<ElementTask>.from(listElement);
        userMap[f.documentID] = listElement2;

        for (int i = 0; i < listElement2.length; i++) {
          if (listElement2.elementAt(i).isDone == false) {
            userMap.remove(f.documentID);
            if (cardColor.isNotEmpty) {
              cardColor.removeLast();
            }

            break;
          }
        }
        if (listElement2.length == 0) {
          userMap.remove(f.documentID);
          cardColor.removeLast();
        }
        listElement.clear();
      }).toList();

      return new List.generate(userMap.length, (int index) {
        return new GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              new PageRouteBuilder(
                pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => new DetailPage(
                      user: widget.user,
                      i: index,
                      currentList: userMap,
                      color: cardColor.elementAt(index),
                    ),
                transitionsBuilder:
                    (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
                        new ScaleTransition(
                          scale: new Tween<double>(
                            begin: 1.5,
                            end: 1.0,
                          ).animate(
                            CurvedAnimation(
                              parent: animation,
                              curve: Interval(
                                0.50,
                                1.00,
                                curve: Curves.linear,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: ScaleTransition(
                            scale: Tween<double>(
                              begin: 0.0,
                              end: 1.0,
                            ).animate(
                              CurvedAnimation(
                                parent: animation,
                                curve: Interval(
                                  0.00,
                                  0.50,
                                  curve: Curves.linear,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: child,
                          ),
                        ),
              ),
            );
          },
```

[image]

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Try docs instead of documents.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/66261228/5812524

Comment: Okay I have tried docs but it gives me an new error on forEach

Comment: what error you are getting in forEach

Comment: The method 'forEach' isn't defined for the type 'Function'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'forEach'.

Answer (score 2):

```
documents are now replaced with 
QuerySnapshot documents=snapshot.data.docs
```

Comment: Okay. Should I just change documents to docs?

Comment: yes
QuerySnapshot contains list of documents apply for each loop and parse the document

Comment: Okay but i get this error instead: The method 'forEach' isn't defined for the type 'Function'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'forEach'.

Comment: you applying function on document which is not list 
apply on  
 snapshot.data.docs.forEach((e){});

Comment: Should I replace snapshot.data.docs.map<List>((f){  with snapshot.data.docs.forEach((e){});  ?

Comment: yes if  you want to add different data in other list but if ypu have same list and you want to assign data to that list just map than parse the specific model than to list function all data will be directly assigned to that list

Comment: Okay do you mean like the answer I posted below?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code but it gives me error on last row:

**The method 'toList' isn't defined for the type 'Function'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toList'.**

```
getxpenseItems(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
List<ElementTask> listElement = new List(), listElement2;
Map<String, List<ElementTask>> userMap = new Map();

List<String> cardColor = new List();
if (widget.user.uid.isNotEmpty) {
  cardColor.clear();

  snapshot.data.docs.forEach(((f) {
    f.data.forEach((a, b) {
      if (b.runtimeType == bool) {
        listElement.add(new ElementTask(a, b));
      }
      if (b.runtimeType == String && a == "color") {
        cardColor.add(b);
      }
    });
    listElement2 = new List<ElementTask>.from(listElement);
    userMap[f.documentID] = listElement2;

    for (int i = 0; i < listElement2.length; i++) {
      if (listElement2.elementAt(i).isDone == false) {
        userMap.remove(f.documentID);
        if (cardColor.isNotEmpty) {
          cardColor.removeLast();
        }

        break;
      }
    }
    if (listElement2.length == 0) {
      userMap.remove(f.documentID);
      cardColor.removeLast();
    }
    listElement.clear();
  }).toList());
```

Comment: you are doing it in wrong way docs is List<DocumentSnapshot> and DocumentSnapshot is a single document that contains json data in Map<String,dynamic> form